# How to make an Auto Clicker with Java?

Tags: java

So I wanted to make a program that holds down the mouse button for me.

So far I've got this: http://pastebin.com/UTJwdHY7

What I'm wondering is how I can stop it. Also, what I realise is that stopping the button makes no sense as I wouldn't be able to click it anyway. Also some tips on how I've done so far would be nice.

Edit (Adding code):

```
package main;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

public class clickForever extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public static boolean isClicking = false;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}

public void createFrame() { initComponents(); }

public void initComponents() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("AutoClicker");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(true);
    JButton button = new JButton("OKAY");
    JLabel label = new JLabel();

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(350, 67);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel);

    button.addActionListener(new Action() {

        @Override
        public Object getValue(String s) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void putValue(String s, Object o) {}

        @Override
        public void setEnabled(boolean b) {}

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener) {}

        @Override
        public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener) {}

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

            if(isClicking){isClicking = false; return;}
            if(!isClicking){isClicking = true; return;}
        }
    });

    label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", 1, 16));
    label.setText("Click 'OKAY' to start.");
    label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    panel.add(label);
    panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    panel.add(button);

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws java.awt.AWTException, java.lang.InterruptedException {
    clickForever clickForever = new clickForever();
    Robot rbt = new Robot();

    clickForever.createFrame();

    while(true){
        if(isClicking) rbt.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        if(!isClicking) ;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you could add timer, so it will do clicks only for some period of time, or you could wait for key combination

Answer (score 0):

Add a key listener to the frame, and when the key is pressed, stop the pressing. Note that this will not work if the frame goes out of focus, in which case you would have to listen for a global key press, which I believe would be much more difficult.

Comment: There are libraries for global key listening.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this to end your program and try link it to the press of a button.

Code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Statement 1");
        System.exit(0);
        System.out.println("Statement 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: This in no way answers the questions asked.